# Bouncing ball game tkinter canvas

Tags: python, animation, canvas, tkinter, game-physics

I write a game in python in which the goal is to bounce the ball off the platform.
Everything works pretty well, but the platform's movement is not that smooth. Could you help me make the platform movement more smooth? If the code isn't too clear, I'm sorry, but I'm new in python

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

width = 900
height = 500

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()

x = random.randrange(700)

ball = canvas.create_oval(x+10, 10, x+50, 50, fill='green')

platform_y = height - 20
platform = canvas.create_rectangle(width//2-50, platform_y, width//2+50, platform_y+10, fill='black')

xspeed = 2
yspeed = 2
skore = 0
body = 0

def move_ball():
  global xspeed
  global yspeed
  x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(ball)
  if x1 <= 0 or x2 >= width:
    xspeed = -xspeed
  if y1 <= 0:
    yspeed = 10
  elif y2 == platform_y: 
    cx = (x1 + x2) // 2
    px1, _, px2, _ = canvas.coords(platform)
    if px1 <= cx <= px2:
      yspeed = -10
    else:
      canvas.create_text(width//2, height//2, text='Game Over', font=('Arial Bold', 32), fill='red')
      return
  canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
  canvas.after(20, move_ball)

def board_right(event):
  x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(platform) 
  if x2 < width:
    dx = min(width-x2, 10)
    canvas.move(platform, dx, 0)

def board_left(event):
  x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(platform)
  if x1 > 0:
    dx = min(x1, 10)
    canvas.move(platform, -dx, 0)

canvas.bind_all('<Right>', board_right)
canvas.bind_all('<Left>', board_left)

move_ball()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want smother movement then you want to reduce the after time to say 10ms and then also reduce the distance by half that the ball moves. This will improve on smoothness. So the idea is to move a shorter distance more often. That is the only way that I am aware of to improve smoothness of motion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the speed of the platform is dependent on the auto-repeat speed of your keyboard.

Instead of moving once for each `<Right>` or `<Left>` event, use a key press to start the platform moving in the desired direction and a key release to stop the platform moving. Then, use `after` to repeatedly move the platform in the given direction.

Example:

```
after_id = None
def platform_move(direction):
    """
    direction should be -1 to move left, +1 to move right,
    or 0 to stop moving
    """
    global after_id
    speed = 10
    if direction == 0:
        canvas.after_cancel(after_id)
        after_id = None
    else:
        canvas.move(platform, direction*speed, 0)
        after_id = canvas.after(5, platform_move, direction)

canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Right>", lambda event: platform_move(1))
canvas.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Right>", lambda event: platform_move(0))
canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Left>", lambda event: platform_move(-1))
canvas.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Left>", lambda event: platform_move(0))
```

The above code doesn't handle the case where you might press both keys at the same time, but that can be handled with a little additional logic. The point is to show how you can use the keys to start and stop an animation.

Comment: but when I hold right or left arrow it just go so quick and doesnt stop

Comment: You can speed it up or slow it down with the `speed` variable, along with changing the `5` provided to `after`. As for not stopping, that's simply a matter of checking the coordinates and having it stop when it reaches an edge. The point is to show that you can set up an animation loop, and then having the events stop and start the animation rather than the events _being_ the animation.